# Parse XML contains incrementing namespace numbers and multiple namespaces

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

Parse XML contains incrementing namespace numbers and multiple namespaces, this xml is a service which can't be updated.  The original approach was to simply ummarshal it to the java objects and be on our way.  The provider uses older tools Castor to create the message, which we have no access to.  The plan is to parse it then marshal/unmarshal it.

```
        <TESTXmlResponse xmlns="TEST/TESTXmlResponse">
          <firstRequest>
           <ns1:xmlRquest xmls:ns1="TEST/XMLRequest">
            <ns2:username xmls:ns2="TEST/XMLUserNameRequest">
              <ns3:value xmls:ns3=TEST/XMLValueRequest">test</ns3:value>
            </ns2:username>
           </ns1:xmlRquest>
          </firstRequest>
          <data>
            <ns4:name xmls:ns4="TEST/XMLConstants">name1</ns4:name>
            <ns5:value xmls:ns5=TEST/XMLConstants">data1</ns5:value>
          </data>  
          <data>
            <ns6:name xmls:ns6="TEST/XMLConstants">name2</ns6:name>
            <ns7:value xmls:ns7=TEST/XMLConstants">data2</ns7:value>
          </data> 
          <data>
            <ns8:name xmls:ns8="TEST/XMLConstants">name3</ns8:name>
            <ns9:value xmls:ns9=TEST/XMLConstants">data3/ns9:value>
          </data> 
        </TESTXmlResponse>   
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
     
    import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
    import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
     
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
     
     
    public class Main 
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
        ArrayList<String> constants = new ArrayList<String>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new 
        FileInputStream(newfile("constants.xml")));
             
        Get XPath expression
        XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(doc));
        XPathExpression expr = 
        xpath.compile("//firstRequest/ns1:xmlRequest/ns2:username/ns3:value/text()"); 
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
             
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
           constants.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
        if (constants.size() > 0){
          System.out.println(constants);
        }
    }
    class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext 
    {
        private Document sourceDocument;
     
        public NamespaceResolver(Document document) {
            sourceDocument = document;
        }
     
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
                return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
            } else {
                return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
            }
        }
     
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return sourceDocument.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
        }
     
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

nodelist returned from the expr is where the issue lies, isn't null, but the length is zero 0.
I've looked at several examples, this one seems to be the closet to a solution. The XPathExpression expr appears to be the issue.  Refining it for each case would seem to be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Horrible, isn't it. I've come across files like this, they were being generated by some software package which I think has since been improved. (Using thousands of namespace prefixes is quite likely to perform very badly, because it's not what parsers are expecting). But you need to explain exactly what problem you're having. Unless the XML parser itself blows up, you shouldn't have a problem at the application level, because you should be ignoring namespace prefixes and only looking at namespace URIs.